# Deploying ASP.NET Core Docker image from x86 to ARM (Raspberry Pi) in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, raspberry-pi

I've got Docker setup on a Raspberry Pi 4 and I want to deploy a ASP.NET Core 3.1 app (The Razor pages movie example app) to my Pi via Docker Hub. When I pull the image from Docker hub and try to run it, I get the error

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error
```

I've built my Docker image on a Windows 10 x64 PC. When inspecting the Docker image on my Pi, I can see that the architecture is wrong

```
"Architecture": "amd64",
```

It should be possible to build a Docker image targeting ARM on a x64 machine [since last year](https://techcrunch.com/2019/04/24/docker-partners-with-arm/), but somehow my image is built targeting x64 instead. I've changed my Dockerfile to target linux-arm

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["RazorMovies/RazorMovies.csproj", "RazorMovies/"]
RUN dotnet restore "RazorMovies/RazorMovies.csproj" -r linux-arm
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/RazorMovies"
RUN dotnet build "RazorMovies.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build -r linux-arm

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "RazorMovies.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish -r linux-arm

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RazorMovies.dll"]
```

and I've changed the target runtime-setting found in Build -> Publish in VS2019 to target linux-arm as well as shown in the image below.

[image: Docker Puslish settings in VS 2019]

I know that my Pi is capable of running ASP.NET Core apps through Docker, I've run the same app through Docker by using the example found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/tree/master/samples/aspnetapp). That image shows the architecture as arm instead of amd64.

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8000:80 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:aspnetapp
```

What am I missing for my image to be built targeting ARM instead of x64?

Answer (score 16):

Found the solution, I also needed to change the base from

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
```

to

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim-arm32v7 AS base
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your findings. It worked for me :)

Comment: Naming is explained under .NET Core Tag Scheme in [Staying up-to-date with .NET Container Images](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/staying-up-to-date-with-net-container-images/).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this page for different docker image tags for dotnet
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk/

I just trying one of the ones in the arm32 section, because I couldn't get dotnet restore to run (even when there were no dependencies to restore).